# How to uncover a DIV covered by other DIVs without hiding them?

Tags: html, css

I have four DIVs that split the screen evenly into 4 parts. There is another full-screen DIV for canvas.

I want to make it possible that those DIVs don't obstruct each other – that is, if the user clicks on a link in the smaller (one of the 4) DIV, they get this link, if the user clicks on the canvas element in the big DIV, that element responds.

Here's the code... Thank you!

```
#graph-container {
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: blink 2s linear 0s;
}


#NW { z-index: 10; position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:0;   left:0; }
#NE { z-index: 10; position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:0;   left:50%; }
#SW { z-index: 10; position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:50%; left:0; }
#SE { z-index: 10; position:fixed; width:50%; height:50%; top:50%; left:50%; }
```

Comment: Use absolute position for your 4 div. Also for better answer post your markup

Comment: made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/42wyJ/ it seems to work, so you're saying you want a canvas behind the four elements to be clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pointer-events you can click through the overlay div, but have the overlay contain clickable elements.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/42wyJ/5/

```
#NW{
    pointer-events:none;
}
#NW * { 
    pointer-events:auto;

}
```

[Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: But now links in the upper layer aren't clickable as OP asked.  I think this is impossible without some clever scripting.

Comment: ahh you can reset pointer-events on the child elements to auto, this allows clicks on the upper layer too! http://jsfiddle.net/42wyJ/5/